# How does one go about fixing a pixelation issue?

Tags: crash, amd-radeon

I've been having a lot of trouble with pixelation and also in-game display driver crashes. At first I thought the problem may have been my graphics card (Sapphire 5750) but I have RMA'd it three times and I'm still having trouble. So what I think it might be is my PSU, its 650Watt but its made by Azza so it was cheap and not made by a necessarily good company. Or maybe it could be the CPU (AMD Phenom Black Edition 3.4Ghz) It runs hot (60C) but it passes Everest's test. Someone told me it could be the memory (8GB DDR3) but I don't really see how RAM has anything to do with my problem. So what are some of you suggestions?

Here is a video a made awhile ago of what is happening. http://www.metacafe.com/watch/4392213/ati_radeon_5750/

That was just a stress test most games tend to just freeze and crash or lock my system up.

Comment: Just to be safe: Did you try different monitors, different monitor cables, moving the computer? Also, what is your card's temperature? Video to me looks like graphics card which is overheating.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like graphics card is overheating, as Andreja says. Is the graphics card fan spinning?

Try leaving the cover off of your computer (with a room fan blowing into it, if possible) and see if the problem goes away. If your system's hot inside then the graphics card may not be able to keep itself cool enough, even if its fan still works.

You can monitor the card temperature with [GpuZ](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/). Click "log to file" on the Sensors tab and run til it crashes, then check the log file.

Answer (score 1):

Very likely a graphics card issue, or a power supply issue.

Does it happen immediately out of the box? Of the three cards you've had, were they faulty immediately, or did it take some time? If the cards appeared to be dead out of the box, I would consider the PSU.

I think if it was a RAM issue you would be seeing blue screens and program crashes, but you haven't reported any of these.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before and that may in fact be a RAM issue. Troubleshoot this by taking out 1 stick at a time until the problem goes away. It could also be a cable connection or the monitor, or even the monitor itself. I would investigate both those possibilities.